# Is there a way to import Font-Size to Photoshop from an Excel File?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, font-size

I know, we can define layers(e.g. text layers) as variables and import data to change the contents of these layers.

> (Image -> Variables -> Define)

But I have an excel file with lot of rows of texts and their font sizes. Is it possible to define the font size as a variable, as well? or is there another way to import it and don't change it manually?

Comment: I think you'd need scripting. Variables don't typically refer to *structure* only content.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, you're right... I achieved it with scripting.

Comment: Feel free to answer if you have a solution @Milad `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a small code to change the font-size:

```
this.openExcelFile();

function openExcelFile()
{
    var excelFile = File("H:/App/Banner/script/Txt.csv");
    excelFile.open("r");
    
    var wholeFile = excelFile.read().split("end");
    excelFile.close();

    for(var i = 1; i <= wholeFile.length; i++)
    {
        this.addToPhotoshop(wholeFile[i]);
    } 
}

function addToPhotoshop(rows)
{
    rows = rows.split(";");

    var txt = rows[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
    var writer = decodeURI(rows[1].replace("\n", "\r").replace("\n", "\r").replace("\n", "\r").replace("\n", "\r"));
    var smiley     = rows[2];
    var fontSize   = Math.floor(parseInt(rows[3]));

    var activeDoc = app.activeDocument;

    var mainLyricLayer  = activeDoc.layerSets.getByName("lyrics").artLayers.getByName("mainLyric").textItem;
    var mainRapperLayer = activeDoc.artLayers.getByName("writer").textItem;
    var mainSmileyLayer = activeDoc.artLayers.getByName("smiley").textItem;
    
    mainLyricLayer.contents = rapperText + " " + smiley;
    mainLyricLayer.size     = fontSize;

    mainRapperLayer.contents = rapperName;

    this.exportJpg(rows[11]);
    
    return;
}

function exportJpg(counter) 
{  
    var fullFilePath = "H:/App/Banner/script/export/" + app.activeDocument.name.split('.')[0] + "-" + counter + '.jpeg'
    var idsave = stringIDToTypeID("save");
    var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idas = stringIDToTypeID("as");
    var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idextendedQuality = stringIDToTypeID("extendedQuality");
    desc6.putInteger(idextendedQuality, 12);
    var idscans = stringIDToTypeID("scans");
    desc6.putInteger(idscans, 5);
    var idmatteColor = stringIDToTypeID("matteColor");
    var idmatteColor = stringIDToTypeID("matteColor");
    var idnone = stringIDToTypeID("none");
    desc6.putEnumerated(idmatteColor, idmatteColor, idnone);
    var idJPEG = stringIDToTypeID("JPEG");
    desc5.putObject(idas, idJPEG, desc6);
    var idin = stringIDToTypeID("in");
    desc5.putPath(idin, new File(fullFilePath));
    var iddocumentID = stringIDToTypeID("documentID");
    desc5.putInteger(iddocumentID, 219);
    var idlowerCase = stringIDToTypeID("lowerCase");
    desc5.putBoolean(idlowerCase, true);
    var idsaveStage = stringIDToTypeID("saveStage");
    var idsaveStageType = stringIDToTypeID("saveStageType");
    var idsaveSucceeded = stringIDToTypeID("saveSucceeded");
    desc5.putEnumerated(idsaveStage, idsaveStageType, idsaveSucceeded);
    executeAction(idsave, desc5, DialogModes.NO);
}
```